# ethernet RX/TX drops to zero, is it normal? No problems at all discovered

Tags: ethernet, debian-wheezy, eth0

I am using `Debian Wheezy 7.1 [3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux]`
and when monitoring eth0 via Slurm or built-in System monitor I am getting:

```
Current RX Speed: 1883.11 KB/s           Current TX Speed: 9123.94 KB/s
```

and then

```
Current RX Speed: 0.00 KB/s              Current TX Speed: 0.00 KB/s
```

I have not discovered any problems with it, but is it as it should be?

```
Errors on Receiving: 0                Errors on Transmission: 0
```

System monitor graph
[image]

Comment: It is indeed not all that uncommon for servers to be idle sometimes. It might be unlikely or impossible in you use-case though, but that requires more detailed knowledge of your system and application(s).

Comment: Clients are downloading/uploading data for hours, it is impossible to have server idle. But while uploading or download to and from the server I did not notice any problems or drops at all, so I am curious if this happens to more people or it is something maybe with my ethernet card or problems with switch in datacenter.

Comment: Might be network congestion control and/or traffic shaping somewhere on the path between your server and your clients.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will move to more serious datacenter in 2 weeks, so will report here if it is Debian's problem or datacenter's.